# Utilizar UFW en Ubuntu para denegar un IP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall

Estoy haciendo pruebas en Ubuntu con UFW, estaba probando a denegar mi dispositivo móvil creando una regla de la siguiente manera:

```
sudo ufw deny from 187.252.19.110
```

Es la ip pública de mi dispositivo movil, pero no hace nada, puedo seguir conectándome a mis paginas web y creando consultas, etc, me gustaría tener alguna orientación de cual puede ser el problema del porque no bloquea mi ip, así aparece el estado actual de mi Firewall:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuentanos en qué red están ambos dispositivos... por ejemplo, una común: `ambos están en una (la misma, quiero decir) red inalambrica`. Si están en redes diferentes, a través de qué redes pasa el tráfico entre ambos equipos?

Comment: Como sabes que esa es la IP de tu celular?

Comment: El servidor está en una VM de Google Cloud, yo estoy conectado desde mi casa a mi Wifi, la IP publica la conseguí buscando en internet cual es mi ip publica, además al hacer consultas Nginx guarda la ip desde la que estoy haciendo consultas.

Comment: Esta pregunta es *off-topic*, tal vez si la realizas en [su] podrías recibir respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque está fuera de la temática del sitio, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic].